# hslavich / OneloginSamlBundle problem on the acs route

Tags: symfony, saml-2.0

I installed and configured the bundle as indicated in the readme file.
I success to be redirected to the azure login page. After that I input email and password, I'am redirected to the website.

But the process to be logged into my website seems broken.
I'am redirected to /saml/acs with an error.

Here is the log message:
`request.INFO: Matched route "saml_acs". {"route":"saml_acs","route_parameters":{"_controller":"Hslavich\\OneloginSamlBundle\\Controller\\SamlController::assertionConsumerServiceAction","_route":"saml_acs"},"request_uri":"https://myapp.com/saml/acs","method":"POST"} []
[2020-06-11 11:50:57] security.ERROR: Found attributes: Array (     [sessionIndex] => _6789dbcf-b1a7-44b5-8e55-817affff1900 )  [] []
[2020-06-11 11:50:57] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Exception: "Attribute 'uid' not found in SAML data" at /var/www/myapp/vendor/hslavich/oneloginsaml-bundle/Security/Firewall/SamlListener.php line 57 {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Attribute 'uid' not found in SAML data at /var/www/myapp/vendor/hslavich/oneloginsaml-bundle/Security/Firewall/SamlListener.php:57)"} []`

What do I miss ? Do I have to create my own acs action ?

Here is my configuration
config file:

```
idp:
        entityId: 'https://sts.windows.net/xxxXXXxxxXXX/'
        singleSignOnService:
            url: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxXXXxxxXXX/saml2'
            binding: 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect'
        singleLogoutService:
            url: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxXXXxxxXXX/saml2'
            binding: 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect'
        x509cert: 'xxxXXXxxxXXXxxxXXXxxxXXXxxxXXXxxxXXXxxxXXXxxxXXX'
    sp:
        entityId: 'https://myapp.com/saml/metadata'
        assertionConsumerService:
            url: 'https://myapp.com/saml/acs'
            binding: 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST'
        singleLogoutService:
            url: 'https://myapp.com/saml/logout'
            binding: 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect'
        privateKey: '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
                    xxxXXXxxxXXXxxxXXXxxxXXXxxxXXXxxxXXX
                     -----END PRIVATE KEY-----'

    # Optional settings
    baseurl: 
    strict: true
    debug: true
    security:
        nameIdEncrypted:       false
        authnRequestsSigned:   false
        logoutRequestSigned:   false
        logoutResponseSigned:  false
        wantMessagesSigned:    false
        wantAssertionsSigned:  false
        wantNameIdEncrypted:   false
        requestedAuthnContext: true
        signMetadata: false
        wantXMLValidation: true
        signatureAlgorithm: 'http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256'
        digestAlgorithm: 'http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256'
    contactPerson:
        technical:
            givenName: 'Tech User'
            emailAddress: 'techuser@example.com'
        support:
            givenName: 'Support User'
            emailAddress: 'supportuser@example.com'
```

And my security file:

```
firewalls:
        app:
            pattern:    ^/
            anonymous: true
            saml:
                # Match SAML attribute 'uid' with username.
                # Uses getNameId() method by default.
                username_attribute: uid
                # Use the attribute's friendlyName instead of the name
                use_attribute_friendly_name: true
                check_path: /saml/acs
                login_path: /saml/login
            logout:
                path: /saml/logout
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            anonymous: ~

            form_login:
                login_path: login
                check_path: login
                default_target_path: homepage
                always_use_default_target_path: true

            logout:
                path:   logout
                target: login

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/saml/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/saml/metadata, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }

    access_denied_url: login
```

I miss something I guess. Thank you by advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the following option was causing attributes from the SAML assertion not to be parsed correctly, resulting in exactly the same outcome as you're seeing (`sessionIndex` being the only recognized "attribute"):

```
use_attribute_friendly_name: true
```

I needed to change it to:

```
use_attribute_friendly_name: false
```

Then the attributes array got populated correctly.

PS: Additionally, in my case, I had to change the `username_attribute` from `uid` to `email` too, since there was no `uid` attribute in "my" SAML assertion.